# Fail to install npm library - no directory created in node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not able to successfully install node libraries. I can see the library with 'npm -g list' but there is no directory in node_modules and the same error about missing library comes up after I install the library.

I am not administrator on my machine but do not get any error messages about privileges.

See the following commands

```
> npm -g list
...
+-- minipass@2.6.0
| +-- safe-buffer@5.2.1
| `-- yallist@3.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@8.2.14, required by @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @ngrx/store@8.3.0, required by @ngrx/effects@8.3.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @ngrx/store@8.3.0, required by @ngrx/entity@8.3.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@^2.6.0, required by fs-minipass@1.2.7
```

```
> npm -g install minipass@2.6.0
+ minipass@2.6.0
updated 1 package in 0.405s
```

```
> npm -g list
...
+-- minipass@2.6.0
| +-- safe-buffer@5.2.1
| `-- yallist@3.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@8.2.14, required by @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @ngrx/store@8.3.0, required by @ngrx/effects@8.3.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @ngrx/store@8.3.0, required by @ngrx/entity@8.3.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@^2.6.0, required by fs-minipass@1.2.7
```

I also do not see the minipass library installed:

```
>ls .\node_modules\ | Select-String "minipass"

fs-minipass
minipass-collect
minipass-fetch
minipass-flush
minipass-json-stream
minipass-pipeline
minipass-sized
```

I never ran 'npm init' as I got the source from github so think I don't need to do it.

Software versions are

Windows 10

npm is version 6.13.4

Comment: Did you run `npm install` from the project directory to create the folder and download the dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` will create the directory and download dependencies, inside your project directory.

`npm -g install` will create the directory and download dependencies, but in a global folder, outside your project.

`npm init` will only create `package.json`.